# datetime in pyes results

Tags: python, elasticsearch, pyes

I am indexing and then querying an dictionary that contains a datetime

Some documents in the results contain a string representation of the date and some return and actual datetime.

The actual documents that have the datetime change if I re_index.

I am not using a custom mapping, I'm just letting elastic search decide the mapping, could this be part of the problem?

Comment: Please provide sample input, expected output and your code so far.

Comment: tbh i would recomend using pyelasticsearch, or python-elasticsearch (just called elasticsearch in pypi) for low level elasticsearch libraries. The former being well maintained the later being the newly released "official" wrapper from elasticsearch.com

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that there is a bug in pyes: https://github.com/aparo/pyes/issues/311